# Sed: extract servername from string

Tags: linux, sed

I want to use sed to extract `servername` from `filenames_for_severname_all`

```
echo "filenames_for_servername_all" | sed -n 's|filenames_for_\(*\)_all|\1|p'
```

The above returns nothing. Can anyone explain?

Comment: `cut -d_ -f3 filename`

Comment: Your missing the all important `.` in your backreference. But don't forget it is greedy!

Answer (score 3):

Your regular expression is invalid, it's missing a token before the `*` modifier (e.g. `.` which will match any character):

```
echo "filenames_for_servername_all" | sed -n 's|filenames_for_\(.*\)_all|\1|p'
```

You can also try with `grep`:

```
echo "filenames_for_servername_all" | grep -o 'filenames_for_\(.*\)_all'
```

Answer (score 3):

Pure BASH way:

```
s="filenames_for_servername_all"
[[ "$s" =~ _for_([^_]+) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
servername
```

OR awk:

```
awk -F_ '{print $3}' <<< "$s"
servername
```

OR cut:

```
cut -d_ -f3 <<< "$s"
servername
```